# VBA Excel 2010 How do you swap out a connection

Tags: vba, connection, excel-2010, ado

I have one connection pointing to an external excel file. All of my pivot tables are pointing to this connection. Is there any way to swap out my connection without having to change any pivot tables.

I wrote code that uses ADO to read from a password protected excel file. However, I want to change the connection using this new connection I am making when the workbook starts up.

Here is the code so far.

```
Public Sub readFile()
Dim xl As Object
Dim conn As New ADODB.connection
Dim recSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conString As String
Dim wkbName As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim DBPath As String

'Path to excel file
DBPath = "path\to\file.xlsx"
Set xl = GetObject(DBPath)

'Name of table
wkbName = "[table1$]"

conString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

'Query
SQL = "select * from " & wkbName

'Open connection
conn.Open conString

'Itterate over record set
Set recSet = New ADODB.Recordset
recSet.Open SQL, conn

'Print out col1 from table
Do Until recSet.EOF
    'process your data here
    Debug.Print recSet!Data
    recSet.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Question unclear. It sounds like you would just change the path `DBPath` but I guess it depends upon how your data is set up on the sheet. If you are pulling in data from ADO and placing it in the table which is the source for the pivot tables then "it just works™"

Comment: I figured this out. But could I ask you a follow up question to this?

Comment: I wrote some VBA to change all pivot table connections to a new connection. How can I in VBA create a new conneciton in code. I am using     conString = "ODBC;Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
    
    SQL = "select * from [Merged$]"
    
    Connections.Add "Name", "Connection with pswd", conString, SQL. But I get an object required error.

Comment: Please write the answer to this question in the answer box and then select that as the correct answer by using the green checkmark. Then open a new question and be very specific about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to change the connection for all existing pivot tables. Replace connection name with name of connection and replace workbookName with name of workbook

```
Sub changeConnection()
  Dim pTable As Variant
  Dim sheet As Variant
  Dim workBookName As String 

 workBookName = "filename.xlsm"      

  For Each sheet In Workbooks(workBookName).Worksheets
      For Each pTable In sheet.PivotTables
          pTable.changeConnection Workbooks(workBookName ).Connections("connection name")
      Next pTable
   Next sheet
End Sub
```